# Create an Array in For loop without running over the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, css

I'm trying to do a college project.
I'm supposed to create 'Notes' add them to an array and keep them in my local storage.
Now the notes should be created with a Fade in effect (transition) using CSS3.
Everything works perfectly until I create the second note at which point my whole array is run over again which makes all the notes to appear in fade.

CSS:

```
.note_input {
    height:255px;
    width:200px;
    background-image:url('../img/notebg.png');
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-left:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    animation: fadein 0.3s; 
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.3s;
}
    @keyframes fadein {
        from {
            opacity:0;
        }
        to {
            opacity:1;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
        from {
            opacity:0;
        }
        to {
            opacity:1;
        }
    }
```

And this is my JS to create the Array + Note itself:

```
function AddNote (){
    var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var date = d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
    var n = new NoteCrt(input,time,date);
    notes.push(n);
    Note();
}
function Note(){
    var note_d = "<div>";
    for (var i = 0 ; i < notes.length ; i++) {
        note_d += "<span id='fade' class='note_input'>" + "<div class='flow' ><p>"+notes[i].input+"</p></div></br>" + "</br>" +"Time:  "+ notes[i].time + "</br>" +"Date:  "+ notes[i].date;
        note_d +=  "</span>";
    }
    note_d += "</div>";
    document.getElementById("note_div").innerHTML = note_d;
    notes_j = JSON.stringify(notes, null, " ");
    localStorage.setItem("NOTE",notes_j);
    notes_p = JSON.parse(notes_j);
    console.log(notes_p);
}
```

What happens is that all the notes that are present are recreated with a fade in effect every time...
Any help?

Comment: You should just create the new one as a DOM node, and append that to #node_div.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to split this functionality over multiple functions.

All you need to do is create the new note and append it to the DOM, instead of recreating all the HTML every time.

```
function AddNote (){
    var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var date = d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
    var n = new NoteCrt(input,time,date);
    notes.push(n);

    // store
    notes_j = JSON.stringify(notes, null, " ");
    localStorage.setItem("NOTE",notes_j);
    notes_p = JSON.parse(notes_j);
    console.log(notes_p);

    // show
    for (var i = 0 ; i < notes.length ; i++) {
       var new_note = document.createElement("span");
       new_note.id="fade"; new_note.class="note_input";
       new_note.innerHTML += "<div class='flow' ><p>"+notes[i].input+"</p></div></br>" + "</br>" +"Time:  "+ notes[i].time + "</br>" +"Date:  "+ notes[i].date;
    }
    document.getElementById("note_div").appendChild(new_note);
}
```

Comment: it just creates another div and posts all the notes there, leavin the first notes created at their place, and they all still get the fade in effect globally.

Comment: This work? It was tricky figuring out what's a note and what's not ;P

Comment: Not trying to be mean! thanks for the help!!!!
it just creates anoter div section below the first notes and recreates the whole array there+new note

Comment: Right. Could you make a jsFiddle so I can see what's going on?

Comment: Basically, I removed the loop, and made a ShowNote function, which accepts any note data object. This way, it can be used to show the existing notes when the page loads, as well as add new ones later on. The Deletion code had to be changed to remove the HTML element, rather than rewrite the whole div, also.

Comment: OMG IT WORKSSSS but one last thing, 
1st, is it possible to add the text into an input type =  text ?
Also, when I delete the notes they don't get deleted from the local storage so when I refresh they are still there :O...

Comment: Scratch that, only the delete thing from the local storage..
its ok in a <p>

Comment: I've tweaked the deletion function to save. Also created a save() function so you don't have to rewrite the code every time. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/640kxd0d/2/)

Comment: Dude thank you so much . I learned so much from this I went through the code so many times. Helped me a bunch and saved my ass as my project is due today.

Answer (score 0):

```
function AddNote (){
  var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var date = d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
  var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
  var n = new NoteCrt(input, time, date);

  var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("NOTE")) || [];
  notes.push(n);
  console.log(notes);
  localStorage.setItem("NOTE", JSON.stringify(notes, null, " "));

  var node_div = document.getElementById("note_div");
  var el = document.createElement('span');

  el.id = "fade";
  el.classList.add('note_input');
  el.innerHTML =
    "<div class='flow'>" +
      "<p>" + n.input + "</p>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</br>" +
    "</br>" +
    "Time:  " + n.time +
    "</br>" +
    "Date:  " + n.date;
  node_div.appendChild(el);
}
```

You should note that it appears that you are assigning the id `fade` to multiple spans. If that is the case, you should consider making it a class.

Comment: OMG THIS WORKS!!! but how do I then get the data from the local storage?
I am supposed to make sure my notes appear even if the tab is closed, by taking them out of the storage? I added

Comment: I think i have to do it in 2 different functions !... can you split it up?